# Array_walk through 10000 items. Optimization possible?

Tags: php, arrays, query-optimization, laravel

My code is looping through an array with array_walk and that array contains about 10.000 items. The query takes 5.19 seconds to fetch the records but walking through the array takes 19.86 seconds. There probably isn't anything I can do to speed things up?

The questions are returned in json and used by the jquery dataTables plugin to create the table. The plugin doesn't seem to have a problem with that many entries (at least not on firefox).

I'm using the laravel framework. See controller code below

```
$start = microtime(true);
$questions = Question::with(array('tags', 'category'))->get();
$now = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "<h3>FETCHED QUESTIONS: $now</h3>";
array_walk($questions, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = $value->to_array();
    if (empty($value['category'])) $value['category'] = '--';
    if (empty($value['difficulty'])) $value['difficulty'] = '--';
    $value['difficulty'] = HTML::difficulty_label($value['difficulty']);
    $value['approved'] = HTML::on_off_images($value['approved'], 'approved', 'declined');
    $value['active'] = HTML::on_off_images($value['active'], 'active', 'disabled');
    $value['edit_link'] = '<a href="' . URL::to('admin/editquestion/' . $value['id']) . '">' . HTML::image('img/icons/pencil.png', 'edit question') ; '</a>';
});

$spent = microtime(true) - $start - $now;
$now = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "<h3>AFTER WALK: $now ($spent)</h3>";
$out = array('aaData' => $questions);
return json_encode($out);
```

Comment: Might be a better option to implement some form of pagination imho.

Comment: As you are using datatables, use its inherant pagination with server side processing. This is a far more efficient method than to dump all of the table data in in one go.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I must have missed it on the examples page. I will use the serverside processing.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop the array yourself with `foreach` to avoid the penalty of making 10000 function calls:

```
foreach($questions as &$value) {
    $value = $value->to_array();
    if (empty($value['category'])) $value['category'] = '--';
    if (empty($value['difficulty'])) $value['difficulty'] = '--';
    $value['difficulty'] = HTML::difficulty_label($value['difficulty']);
    $value['approved'] = HTML::on_off_images($value['approved'], 'approved', 'declined');
    $value['active'] = HTML::on_off_images($value['active'], 'active', 'disabled');
    $value['edit_link'] = '<a href="' . URL::to('admin/editquestion/' . $value['id']) . '">' . HTML::image('img/icons/pencil.png', 'edit question') ; '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I updated my code. There doesn't seem to be much improvement however. And the timing fluctuates a bit (on my local machine, about 2sec max/try). I think I won't be able to improve this much (like 10 seconds max) without using pagination..